# Error 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row on simple insert into mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table called `barang` and when i want to insert into the table with this code

```
INSERT INTO barang(kode,deposit,brand)
VALUES('13212321','1232131','12312321');
```

it turns error `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` i already search into SO but didnt found out with just case as mine, which part i skip on this?

UPDATE

as mr @P.salmon said here's my trigger on `before insert`, sir

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.tanggal = NOW();
SET NEW.kategori_nama = (SELECT kategori.nama from kategori JOIN barang WHERE 
                         kategori.kode = barang.kategori);
SET NEW.hargadepresiasi = NEW.hargabeli * 2 / 8;
END
```

column for `kategori` and `barang` table :

```
    +---------------------+
    | kategori            |
    +---------------------+
    |                kode |
    |                nama |
    |                no   |                     
    +---------------------+
```

for `barang` table

```
    +---------------+
    | barang        |
    +---------------+
    | kode          |
    | nama          |
    | kategori      |
    | kategori_nama |
    +---------------+
```

so basically, on `kategori_nama` column in `barang` table is still null and i want to fill it with `nama` on `kategori` table with `kategori.kode = barang.kategori`

Comment: There is no sub query in the published code, check triggers on this table..

Comment: i already update the question sir, thank you in advance

Comment: barang.kategori - I don't see this in your insert. Please add table definitions for barang and kategori

Comment: done sir, i put the table and the column, thank you sir

Comment: Impossible you are not populating barang.kategori on the insert

Comment: because when i do ```DESC barang``` it can be NULL values on ```barang.kategori``` so i skipped that in order to reduce time to check where's the error at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this by hand for the value in your update that gives the error

```
SELECT kategori.nama from kategori JOIN barang WHERE 
                         kategori.kode = barang.kategori
```

then you should see the multiple records - then you can decide which of those records your  really intend and rewrite this part of the trigger

these might be what you need:

```
SELECT distinct kategori.nama from kategori JOIN barang WHERE 
                         kategori.kode = barang.kategori
```

or

```
SELECT min( kategori.nama ) from kategori JOIN barang WHERE 
                         kategori.kode = barang.kategori
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i just found out the simple solution is ```Distinct``` or ```min```

Comment: If the trigger is on barang I would expect to see NEW.KATEGORI in the select aka SELECT distinct kategori.nama from kategori  WHERE 
                         kategori.kode = new.kategori the join being redundant..